# NextAuth Pass Props from Server to Client Component

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a NextAuth setup with NextJS13 where I am using a client-side component to load my `layout.tsx` file so I can use `SessionProvider` to wrap my child components for all pages that require authentication.

When I create new `page.tsx` files in the app directory, I have no issues using `getServerSession()` to load the session server-side and load on my page, but I am having trouble trying to determine the best pattern to be able to server-side load the session with my navigation bar.

The navigation bar is located in `layout.tsx`, which is a client-side component and I thought I might be able to get away with referencing this as a server-side component it is throwing an error. The reason I am looking to make the call server-side is to stay consistent and not have a delay in the loading of session information between the pages and navigation on new page loads.

**Rule broken:**

```
cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.
```

**Client error (Appears to try and load server modules):**

```
error - ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
./app/(application)/app/AppNav.tsx
./app/(application)/app/layout.tsx
```

**layout.tsx**:

```
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import '../../globals.css';
import AppNav from './AppNav';

export default function AppLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <SessionProvider>
          <AppNav />
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**AppNav.tsx:**

```
import AppMainNavigation from '@/components/app/universal/navigation/AppMainNavigation';
import { authOptions } from '@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';

export default async function AppNav() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  console.log(`App navigation: ${session}`);
  return <AppMainNavigation />;
}
```

**AppMainNavigation.tsx**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

const AppMainNavigation = () => {
const [MobileMenuState, setMobileMenuState] = useState(false);

return (
  <div>
      <a
        href="#"
        className=""
        onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: '/login' })}
      >
        SignOut
      </a>
      <button
        className="md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(
            `Mobile Menu Button Clicked. Current State ${!MobileMenuState}`
          );
          setMobileMenuState(!MobileMenuState);
        }}
      >
        <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" className="w-6 h-6">
          <path
            className={`${MobileMenuState ? 'hidden' : 'block'}`}
            fillRule="evenodd"
            d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
            clipRule="evenodd"
          ></path>
          <path
            className={`${MobileMenuState ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}
            fillRule="evenodd"
            d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
            clipRule="evenodd"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
  </div>
);
};

export default AppMainNavigation;
```